# How to prevent Android Chrome magnifier (link preview) when user clicks on links that are close to each other?

Tags: android, jquery, google-chrome, zooming, viewport

I know this question has been asked before. But none of the answers are applicable/acceptable to/for my situation. I am desiging a **non-responsive** e-commerce website so completely disabling zooming by setting this meta tag:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='user-scalable=no'/>
```

is **not an option**. But my client is insisting that this effect:

[image]

absolutely has to go. I have been trying to detect touchstart/touchend events and taps so that I can somehow add the meta tag shown above when the user taps and remove it when the user's touchend has fired so that the pinch and double tap zoom is still available. No success yet.

Also I cannot increase the size of the buttons, font etc - UI design changes are not acceptable.

Can anyone provide any ideas of how to tackle this with CSS/JavaScript/jQuery ?

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution to this, Larry?

Comment: No @ManuelOtto sorry, I spend a couple of weeks but couldn't figure that one out - instead my business analyst convinced the client to build a responsive site :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, Larry! Afterall, I managed to avoid this by deactivating the links when a touchstart event occurs and then handle the click logic myself with touchevents & `document.elementFromPoint()`. Not very elegant, but works.

Comment: @ManuelOtto How you deactivate it. can u give solution?

Comment: I have same problem, android version 5.1.1, but only on buttons in a fancybox iframe. Outside fancybox, same button, but no magnification.

Comment: Further to... the error was in the page that launches my fancybox iframe, There, on advise gleaned not sure when/where, I had set maximum-scale=0.8 (on the iframed pages it was maximum-scale=1.0).  Changing 0.8 to 1.0 fixed it. Not sure why 0.8 provoked it in the iframed buttons but not when the same buttons were not iframed.